# How to display sys_refcursor output pl sql with Toad tool

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I have written a query to execute the SP. The execution works fine with this. However, I'm not able to see output results.

```
declare v_rc    sys_refcursor;

begin
   SUSER.TRANS_REP (v_rc  ,'Investments Series','31-12-2012','Dealer Group','All Adv') ;

 end;
```

How to display output result with sys_refcursor. Please help.

note: I tried to print cursor but did not get any help. Also refered this ([How to display a sys_refcursor data in TOAD's DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747823/how-to-display-a-sys-refcursor-data-in-toads-datagrid)  and  https://community.oracle.com/thread/627571), but still no help.

Comment: Use a ref cursor variable. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In `SQL*Plus` you could easily do it using a **refcursor** variable.

```
SQL> var r refcursor
SQL>
SQL> BEGIN
  2    OPEN :r FOR SELECT empno,ename FROM emp;
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print r

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD
      7566 JONES
      7654 MARTIN
      7698 BLAKE
      7782 CLARK
      7788 SCOTT
      7839 KING
      7844 TURNER
      7876 ADAMS

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7900 JAMES
      7902 FORD
      7934 MILLER

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

I guess in TOAD, you have some sort of output options. Select the variables you want to see the values in the output, the ref cursor result set would open in a different window.