# SQL Developer Oracle, how to call procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, execute

I have delcared function like this:

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE proc
(
  P_ID IN INTEGER,
  NAME OUT CHAR,
  SURNAME OUT CHAR,
  TOTAL OUT CHAR
)
 AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT NAME, SURNAME, sum(TOTAL) AS TOT
          INTO NAME,SURNAME,TOTAL
          FROM STATISTICS, PLAYERS, PERSON
          WHERE STATISTICS.SID=P_ID AND PERSON.ID=PLAYERS.SID AND      
          STATISTICS.PLAYERS_SID=PLAYERS.SID
        GROUP BY NAME,SURNAME;
END;
```

Select statement works corectly, but how to call this procedure in Oracle?

I tried something like

```
EXEC proc(4);
```

AND

```
DECLARE
  NAME OUT CHAR,
  SURNAME OUT CHAR,
  TOTAL OUT CHAR

BEGIN
   P_ID := 12 ;
   proc (
   P_ID => P_ID,
   NAME => NAME,    
   SURNAME => SURNAME,
   TOTAL => TOTAL
);
END;
```

but without any success.

Comment: Have you supplied the out parameters as well?

Comment: try anonymous block: `BEGIN proc(4); END;`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Not just that as you need out parameters too.

Comment: what error you get? your procedure just fetch the name surname and total and do nothing with them. You may for example print them to output with dbms_output. (you need to activate the dbms_output in sqldeveloper in the View menu for your session to see the actual outptut )

Comment: Your PL/SQL block has syntax errors and won't work. `IN/OUT` is for parameters and not for local variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> EXEC proc(4);

**EXECUTE** is a `SQL*Plus` command.

You have following options:

- **EXECUTE** in SQL*Plus
- **Call** it in an anonymous **PL/SQL** block.
- **Run** in **SQL Developer** client tool

Let's see all the three ways:

In **SQL*Plus**:

```
SQL> variable v_ename varchar2(20);
SQL> exec get_emp(7788, :v_ename);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print v_ename;

V_ENAME
--------------------------------
SCOTT
```

In an **anonymous PL/SQL block**:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_emp(
  2      i_empno IN emp.empno%TYPE,
  3      o_ename OUT emp.ename%TYPE)
  4  AS
  5  BEGIN
  6    SELECT ename INTO o_ename FROM emp WHERE empno = i_empno;
  7  END;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_ename VARCHAR2(20);
  3  BEGIN
  4    get_emp(7788, v_ename);
  5    dbms_output.put_line('Employee name is '||v_ename);
  6  END;
  7  /
Employee name is SCOTT

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

In **SQL Developer** client tool:

1. Go to **connections** on the left pane.
2. **Expand** the **Procedures**.

[image]

3. **Right click** on the procedure and select "**Run**".

[image]

4. It will open a new window, provide the **Input value** and click **OK**.

[image]

5. The output will be shown in **Output Log** at the bottom as "**Output Variables**".

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply, I will try

Comment: @dreamPr I have added two examples, use whichever suits you. Please mark it as answered, would help others too!

Comment: I've upvoted the answer from the beginning, but now after all the edits it is a too detailed answer. I'm about to withdraw the vote... Just kidding!

Comment: @FlorinGhita LOL :-) have a nice day!

Comment: Thank you @Lalit Kumar B for such a detailed answer.
But how does it work, when procedure returns multiple variables? Like in yor example with O_ENAME, what if I need to return multiple names?

Comment: @dreamPrThat is a completely different question, search for PL/SQL collections. Easiest way is to return a `SYS_REFCURSOR`. With a scalar variable, you can have only a single value. For multiple rows, you need a collection type. I have already answer such questions, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27812983/3989608 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/28298323/3989608. If you like the answers, you could upvote them :-)

Comment: To return multiple names we have to use collections only and that can be easily returned or you can go for ref_cursor.